# Is Tinycore suitable as a day to day os?

Tags: linux

I am relatively new to Linux, but I was wondering if tinycore is stable enough for programing?

Also I cannot figure out how to install Tinycore to the hard drive of the computer, and treat it like a "normal" Linux os, so any pointers here would be greatly apprieciated. Tinycore cannot seem to find my HD, so I am wondering if I am to off base, and expecting too much from this OS.

Comment: May be or may not, depending on your usage. You can surf internet with opera extension. See these article:: 1. http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/install.html 2. http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/install_manual.html

Comment: Please try to be more specific. For example, asking about your specific problem with installation would make a valid question, but current form your post risks to attract opinions rather than answers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll have problems with stability, but maybe access to packages/precompiled software. You say Tiny Core cannot find your disk. Tiny Core should work with a SATA disk; not sure about IDE or SAS (SCSI doesn't work out of the box on the base installation). However, unlike many other systems, you'll have to tell Tiny Core to look for your disk. If you install `cfdisk`, it should be able to tell you what it has identified. There is an installer in the [CorePlus distribution](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/install_manual.html); final installed size is a bit under 40MB.

Is there some reason why you're avoiding, say, Debian? A minimal install weighs in a bit under 600MB or about 1.1GB with a window manager like icewm (and the standard X package). If you're planning to do programming using Tiny Core, you'll probably need a whole host of tools. Debian already includes some tools you might want/need (Python, Perl, and bash come standard), whereas Tiny Core's base install does not include these. And if you throw in GCC, an IDE, and some revision control software, your toolchain and environment will eclipse (no pun intended) the size of your OS.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, Tinycore is *stable* enough. You could use it daily without a significantly higher risk of crashing than another Linux operating system.

However, I'm going to give you a piece of advice: *Don't install Tinycore to your hard drive.* Tinycore is meant to be a recovery OS that takes three minutes to install to a low-capacity USB disk, reboot, and save your PC. It does not even come with the coreutils of *nix. DOS is more complete than Tinycore.

You're wasting your hard drive installing a 6MB OS to it. If you're looking for a tiny distro that runs ridiculously fast, try AntiX. Tinycore simply does not have enough tools to be fully functional for, e.g. a work computer.

Don't install Tinycore to your hard drive. If you've got a hard drive to waste, sell it and buy something useful.